# ASP MVC, expose method to other application (java and php)

Tags: java, php, asp.net-mvc

i need to expose a simple method in my Asp.Net MVC application to other website that are written in php and java:

```
public void Enable(int ObjectIdToEnable)
{
// my code to call data access and set enabled property of my object
}
```

i have poor knowledge of java and php and sono don't know what they can do and what i have to do for estabilish this comunication.

various ipotesis i make:

1. i can simply write it as method in my controller?
2. i have to create a web service?
3. other way?

many thanks

**EDIT:**

some thought on first idea, i can have a void action in my controller

```
public void Enable(int id)
```

and any other application can simply call a link like:

```
http://MyAppName/MyControllerName?Id=34
```

can this call be done in java or php?

Comment: You could write web service, in ASP.NET MVC, than write code in Java to access it. We will not write your Java code, but you will get help if you are stuck on some particular problem ;)

Comment: ok, iam not asking for code but for solutions. since java application is not mine but external iam only searching about how complex will be (we will have to pay for this implementation) and if the same solution can be adopted by php application (external too)